# Erro react-native ao tentar gerar apk

Tags: react-native, apk

Após seguir os passos da documentação [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html), quando chego na parte de executar o comando `gradlew assembleRelease` recebo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem um erro de sintaxe no teu `build.gradle`

Comment: sim reparei nisso e arrumei mas agora tou tendo outro erro

Comment: consigo copilar e gerar a apk mas quando tento abrir no celular nao consigo diz q apresenta falhas continuamente

Comment: Achou alguma solução, Rogerio?